# Why floating causes increased margin at the top?

Tags: css, css-float

Simple CSS question, I've been wondering for a while and I'd like to understand exactly how this works.

Let's say I have the following:

```
<div>
   <p>some text</p>
   <p style="float: left">some text</p>
</div>
```

If I remove the `float: left` from a given `<p>` element, the element and its previous sibling are stacked closer.

**Why floating an element causes this increased margin at its top?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the difference is a behaviour known as [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins).

Note that paragraphs have, by default, a user-agent defined top and bottom margin.

When the second paragraph does not have `float: left`, the bottom margin of the first paragraph and the top margin of the second paragraph are *adjoining* and so *collapse* into each other.

When the second paragraph has `float: left`, those two margins will no longer collapse into each other; they are no longer considered *adjoining* because:

> Two margins are adjoining if and only if:
>
> - both belong to in-flow block-level boxes that participate in the same [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting)
> - [...]

Following the "block formatting context" link reveals that:

> Floats [...] establish new block formatting contexts for their contents.

The spec goes on to say:

> Note the above rules imply that:
>
> - Margins between a floated box and any other box do not collapse (not even between a float and its in-flow children).
> - [...]

Comment: thanks - I suspected something like that as I could see the margins were being collapsed via visual inspectors (firebug etc), but this is great! :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't occur for me on Chrome19.. but this would occur because of your browser's default stylesheet. If you want to prevent against this happening, use margin: 0; padding: 0; on the floated element.

Comment: It does happen in Chrome. If you're trying it in jsFiddle, you're not seeing it because "Normalized CSS" is ticked.